# datagridview doesn't display data

Tags: c#

i want to show the data from the database onto my datagridview control i have used the following piece of code but it is not showing any data when the form loads it just shows and empty datagridview i don't get any errors what am I doing wrong

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        FillData();

    }
    public void FillData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=database; " +
                                   "connection timeout=10"))
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from スコープ", myConnection))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @LolCoder yes there is data in the datatable but the dtagrid view shows the rows but with no data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there is no matching column of datatable with datagridview column....Check the column of datagridview with datatable column....

For test, make `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` to `true` and check whether the datagridview fill the data or not...

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns= true;
```

You can create the datagridview column by following way:

Go to properties of `datagridview` and then go to Columns Section where you can add new column in datagridview according to your datatable....Match `DataPropertyName` with your datatable column and keep `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and then it'll works fine...

Comment: if I set dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns= true; then it shows the data but i want only selcted columns not all the columns from the datatable